# Xcode 6 gradient layer to resize correctly with object resizing a universal app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, interface-builder

Is there a preferred method to add an auto-resizing gradient layer to a UIView or UILabel that will conform to the autolayout constraints set in IB (Xcode 6) and a wAny hAny canvass, using Swift?

For example, I can start with two labels that span universal widths using constraints using an wAny and hAny canvass, but when running the app on an iPad2 simulator, the labels size correctly but not the gradient layer.

I've looked into willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation and adding a notification based on UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, but this is not helpful when the app is loaded in landscape (although once rotated the layers are redrawn and do match).

The only solution I have found is to manally adjust the width of each button to conform to the maximum view width of each (iPad2 in landscape) in the Utilities side panel in Xcode, but that creates "misplaced view" warnings and a messy canvass.

Any other ideas?

Here is what I have:

In viewDidLoad, I send each button through this:

Example:

```
//viewDidLoad --
self.configButton(self.button1!)
self.configButton(self.button2!)
self.configButton(self.button3!)
//

func configButton(theButton: UIButton){

    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame.size = theButton.frame.size
    theButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
    let topR = CGFloat(13.0)
    let topG = CGFloat(55.0)
    let topB = CGFloat(112.0)
    let bottomR = CGFloat(90.0)
    let bottomG = CGFloat(126.0)
    let bottomB = CGFloat(167.0)
    let colorTop = UIColor(red: CGFloat(topR/255.0), green: CGFloat(topG/255.0), blue: CGFloat(topB/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), green: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), blue: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let gradientColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradient.colors = gradientColors
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0] 
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)

    let theCornerRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
    theButton.layer.cornerRadius = theCornerRadius
    theButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    theButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
    theButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Comment: How did you size the gradient layer when you added it? Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by subclassing UIButton, and putting the configureButton method, minus the layer sizing line, in that class. You can then set the frame of the gradient layer equal to the bounds of its super layer (the button's default layer) in layoutSublayersOfLayer because that layer automatically resizes to keep it the same size as the button. You don't need any code in the controller with this approach.

```
class RDButton: UIButton {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureButton()
    }

    func configureButton() {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
        let topR = CGFloat(13.0)
        let topG = CGFloat(55.0)
        let topB = CGFloat(112.0)
        let bottomR = CGFloat(90.0)
        let bottomG = CGFloat(126.0)
        let bottomB = CGFloat(167.0)
        let colorTop = UIColor(red: CGFloat(topR/255.0), green: CGFloat(topG/255.0), blue: CGFloat(topB/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), green: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), blue: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let gradientColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradient.colors = gradientColors
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)

        let theCornerRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = theCornerRadius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    override func layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer: CALayer!) {
        super.layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer)
        gradient.frame = layer.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Now if I want to pass the variable gradientColors to this class of buttons at initialization:

Comment: @user773881, then you need to create a custom initializer that includes an array parameter into which you can pass the colors.

Comment: Yes - but the examples I'm finding for custom initializers with parameters seem to also include passing a frame, which is messing up the IB design. I want the frame of each button to be dictated via the IB canvass layout for a universal app.  All I need to pass is the gradient color array.

Comment: @user773881 If the buttons are made in the storyboard, then you can't use a custom initializer, since initWithCoder is the one that will be called. So, you do need to create a method or a property in the custom class, like you do in your answer. I don't think there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with to pass gradient colors to this new button class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class RDButton: UIButton{

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    var gradientColors: [Int] = []

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func configureButton(thecolors: [Int]) {
        println("thecolors: \(thecolors)")
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

        let topR = CGFloat(thecolors[0])
        let topG = CGFloat(thecolors[1])
        let topB = CGFloat(thecolors[2])
        let bottomR = CGFloat(thecolors[3])
        let bottomG = CGFloat(thecolors[4])
        let bottomB = CGFloat(thecolors[5])

        let colorTop = UIColor(red: CGFloat(topR/255.0), green: CGFloat(topG/255.0), blue: CGFloat(topB/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), green: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), blue: CGFloat(bottomR/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let gradientColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]

        gradient.colors = gradientColors
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)

        let theCornerRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = theCornerRadius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    override func layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer: CALayer!) {
        super.layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer)
        gradient.frame = layer.bounds
    }

}
```

In the View Controller, I did this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySweetButton: RDButton?
// etc for each button

let buttonsgradient = [13,55,112,90,126,167]

override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    mySweetButton?.configureButton(buttonsgradient)
    /// etc for each button
    // ...
}
```

Probably not the optimal way of doing this ...